# Xamarin.Forms DatePicker dialogue color customization

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker, background-color

[DatePicker Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOiE6.png)
I'm developing an app in Xamarin.Forms. I managed to change the accent color of the DatePicker calendar dialog, and now I'm able to apply this color to the "Header" area, but my question is: How can I change the body background color, and also how can I change the font color (numbers color)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picker is a native platform control, so you need to modify if separately in each platform project.

Android:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
<!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
<!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
<!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

<!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>-->
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PickerDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
 //header color
 <item name="colorAccent">#039BE5</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 //number color
 <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
 //body color
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
 //all the dialog color
 <!--<item name="android:background">@android:color/darker_gray</item>-->
 </style>
```

[image]

For iOS, you could use the custom renderer like below. [How to change visual material DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog background color in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67932857/how-to-change-visual-material-datepickerdialog-and-timepickerdialog-background-c)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now this would solve my problem as there is a bug in Dark mode.